# Concat and left join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dynamic query constructor in php that want to achieve a left join based on one concatenation of fields.

```
SELECT CONCAT(A1.RHID, ',', A1.CD_DOC_ID, ',', A1.SEQ) AS pk,
       A1.EMISSOR, A1.DT_EMISSAO, A1.DT_VALIDADE, A2.RHID
FROM rh_id_documentos A1,
     fo_on_workflow A2  left join pk on A2.RHID
WHERE  1 = 1;
```

but always return

> 1146 - Table 'portal_utf8.pk' doesn't exist

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need JOIN conditions!

Comment: This query is wrought with errors.  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Add table definitions, sample table data, and the expected result!

Answer (score 1):

Do the concat part etc in a derived table, which you later left join:

```
select A1.*, A2.RHID
from
    (SELECT CONCAT(A1.RHID, ',', A1.CD_DOC_ID, ',', A1.SEQ) AS pk,
            A1.EMISSOR, A1.DT_EMISSAO, A1.DT_VALIDADE
     FROM rh_id_documentos) A1
LEFT JOIN fo_on_workflow A2  ON A1.pk = A2.RHID
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give an example of what you expect to see, for example if:

```
    RHID = aaa
    CD_DOC_ID = bbb
    SEQ = ccc
```

Then pk will be:

```
    aaa,bbb,ccc
```

Did you really want to concatenate a ',' between each field?

In your query for A1 you are referencing A1 but there is no table with the alias A1, not until the outer scope, I think this should read:

```
    SELECT
        A1.*, A2.RHID
    FROM
        (SELECT 
           CONCAT(RHID, ',', CD_DOC_ID, ',', SEQ) AS pk,
          EMISSOR, DT_EMISSAO, DT_VALIDADE
        FROM 
          rh_id_documentos) A1
    LEFT JOIN 
       fo_on_workflow A2  
    ON 
       A1.pk = A2.RHID
```

Also looking at your query is the join criteria correct, wouldn't it be more correct to expose A1.RHID and join on that?

Comment: yes. I want t concatenate.  I am not experienced n sql, but if i solve the error 1146 - Table 'portal_utf8.pk' doesn't exist , query achieves what i want. I just want that concatenation to be a field. Is that possible